# Add an app to SPO modern site collection using pnp powershell

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, pnp-powershell, office-365-developer

I need to add an app from app catalog to the set of site collections which I need to read Site URL's from csv file using PnP PowerShell script.

Any idea how to do that?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

**PnP PowerShell: Add an app to SharePoint Online site from App Catalog**

`Note:`

You need site owner permissions to be able to add apps to SharePoint Online.

```
#Parameters
$SiteURL = "https://crescent.sharepoint.com/sites/Legal"
$AppName = "Modern Script Editor web part by Puzzlepart"
 
#Connect to SharePoint Online App Catalog site
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -UseWebLogin
 
#Get the App from App Catalog
$App = Get-PnPApp -Scope Tenant | Where {$_.Title -eq $AppName}
 
#Install App to the Site
Install-PnPApp -Identity $App.Id
```

Comment: Thanks for an update, but how to read the site URLS from CSV file and add the app to the multiple site collections?

Comment: Hi, taruki_MS. In my test environment, it is impossible to add app to multiple site collections using PnP PowerShell. If there is any solution in the future, I will share with you as soon as possible. Have a nice day!